# Solving Backward Heat Equation with a Backward Heat Kernel?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, convolution, heat-equation, gaussian

Let $D>0$ be a constant. Imagine we have the following forward heat conduction problem:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t u = D \partial_x^2u &, \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times (0, \infty). \\
u = \phi(x) &, \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
We define the Heat Kernel:
\begin{align*}
\Phi(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi D t}} \exp{\left( \frac{-x^2}{4Dt}\right)} \ .
\end{align*}
A well know solutions to this problem is the one expressed in terms of a convolution
\begin{align*}
u(x,t) = (\Phi * \phi)(x,t) \ .
\end{align*}
Where $*$ is the convolution operator with respect to the spatial variable $x$.

Now we define the backward heat conduction problem:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\partial_t v = -D \partial_x^2v &, \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times (0, T). \\
v = \psi(x) &, \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R} \times \{0\}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
This problem is not as well behaving but if we have Gaussian initial data:
\begin{align*}
\psi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp{\left( \frac{-x^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)} \ .
\end{align*}
Then a possible solution to the Backward problem is
\begin{align*}
v(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi ( \sigma^2-2 D t)}} \exp{\left( \frac{-x^2}{2( \sigma^2-2 D t)}\right)} \ .
\end{align*}
I define $T = \sigma^2/2D$. An interesting observation is that we can write the initial data as a convolution
\begin{align*}
(v * \Phi)(x) = \psi(x) \ .
\end{align*}
Now to my question is it possible to define a Backward Heat Kernel $\Phi^{-1}(x,t)$ in the following way
\begin{align*}
\Phi^{-1}(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi (-D) t}} \exp{\left( \frac{-x^2}{4(-D)t}\right)} \ .
\end{align*}
Such that we have
\begin{align*}
(\Phi^{-1} * v * \Phi)(x,t) &= (\Phi^{-1} *\psi)(x,t) \\
v &= (\Phi^{-1} *\psi)(x,t) \ .
\end{align*}
This integral can ofcourse not make sense in the classical sense, since $\Phi^{-1}$ is not integrable, but is it possible to make sense of it in terms of distributions? And if so can we solve if for other initial data than Gaussian?

#### Edit

I didn't mention that I am interested in the case where $u,v,\phi,\psi$ go to zero for $x$ goint to $\pm \infty$. One can see them as probability distributions. But all comments about how this will work, if possible, is welcome.

Comment: You sure you want a *time zero* condition in a backwards diffusion, and not a *time $T$* condition?

Comment: Yes I am sure. This is the interesting part in my opinion. :)

Comment: my first impression is that this PDE with that bc could have infinite solutions. Let's see what the community says

Comment: You mean when I have no restictions on the solution for what will happen at infinity? :)

Comment: I have made an edit according to your comment.

Comment: I mean an infinite number of solutions..

Comment: Yes, it was more the part "with that bc" that reminded me that I didn't specify that I wanted $u,v,\phi,\psi$ to go to zero with $x$ going to infinity.

Comment: For $t>0$ the function
\begin{align}
\Phi^{-1}(x,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4 \pi (-D) t}} \exp{\left( \frac{-x^2}{4(-D)t}\right)}
\end{align}
is complex and I see convergence problems in $\int_{\mathbb R}\Phi^{-1}(x,t)\,dx$. Is that what you want ?

Comment: I am asking if this integral can be seen as convergent in some other sense. What I mean by "This integral can of course not make sense in the classical sense" in the question is excatly this convergence problem you point out. But I know that some convergence problems can sometime be fixed by switching to a distribution framework, which is what I mean by the question "but is it possible to make sense of it in terms of distributions?". But thanks for your comment if this wasn't clear in my question. :)